# Is compactness a stronger form of continuity?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. We say that a linear operator $T \colon H \to H$ is *compact* if it maps bounded sets to precompact ones, that is, if for every bounded sequence $(a_n)$ in $H$, $(Ta_n)$ has got a convergent subsequence. We can characterize compactness in terms of weak convergence: $T$ is compact if and only if it maps weakly convergent *sequences* into norm convergent ones.

Up to now I would have casually said:

> $T$ is compact iff $T$ is continuous
>   when its domain is equipped with weak
>   topology and its range with norm
>   topology.

and I would not have been alone: I've heard this from more than one of my professors. Well, this turns out to be *false*, as I read on Problem VI.34 of Reed & Simon's *Methods of modern mathematical physics*:

> Show that in a Hilbert space $H$, a map $T \colon H \to H$ is continuous when its domain is given the weak topology and its range the norm topology if and only if $T$ has finite rank!

(the exclamation point is part of the original text).

At the moment this problem is beyond my grasp, since I know almost nothing of the necessary topological tools (that is - nets, Moore-Smith convergence, and the like). But I'm curious about this and wanted to share my curiosity with the community.

Has somebody got any idea on how to prove this, or even some hint that could help me to catch this intuitively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you'll need to understand that a basis of the weak topology consists of the sets
$$
V_{\epsilon, y_1, ..., y_n} = \{x \in H: |(x, y_i)| \lt \epsilon \}
$$
for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ and a finite set of vectors $y_i$. To be more precise: These sets form a neighborhood basis at zero, which is what we'll need for the proof.

Now, if a linear transformation
$$
T: H_{weak} \to H_{norm}
$$ 
is continuous, then the inverse image of the open unit ball in $H_{norm}$ has to contain such a basic weak neighborhood $V_{\epsilon, y_1, ..., y_n}$. If H is infinite dimensional, we can find an $x$ such that $(x, y_i) = 0$ for $i = 1,..., n$. This implies that $k x \in V$ for any $k$, so that $T x = 0$ needs to hold (which implies that the operator norm of $T$ has to be zero).

We may assume that the $y_i$ are orthonormal (why?). Given any $x \in H$, we can write
$$
z = x - \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x, y_i) \; y_i
$$
Now we know that $A z = 0$ by construction, which means that we know $T x$ for any arbitrary $x$, it is
$$
T x = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x, y_i) \; y_i
$$
So much for your concrete question.

Infinite dimensional normed spaces are fundamentally different from finite normed spaces, for example:

- The unit ball is compact iff the space is finite dimensional.

Therefore the compact operators are of interest because they retain some properties from the finite dimensional case in infinte dimensions, as is the weak operator topology, that makes them interesting.

BTW: I think your professors were talking about the fact that compact operators are those that are continuous from the **weak unit ball** of $H_{weak}$ to $H_{norm}$. The restriction to the unit ball is essential, and looking at the proof above you can see which step does not work anymore if we add remove this restriction.

Comment: I made some small corrections, but I didn't want to mess too much with your nice text. One thing I left unchanged since I didn't see a very easy fix that would without doubt be okay with you is that your basis is of course only a neighborhood basis at zero.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see what I can do :-)

Comment: I'm sorry for this long wait, I have had to postpone this question because of my exam schedule. Ok, I understand this argument: at a point you ask "why can we suppose $y_1 \ldots y_n$ to be othonormal?", and I would say, because if they are not we could take $z_1 \ldots z_k$, yielded by a Gram-Schmidt on $y_1 \ldots y_n$, and we have 

$$\max_{j=1 \ldots n} \lvert (x, y_j) \rvert \le C\max_{l=1\ldots k} \lvert (x, z_l)\rvert$$

for some constant $C$. [to be continued...]

Comment: To see this, let $P$ denote orthogonal projection over $\mathrm{span}(y_1 \ldots y_n) = \mathrm{span} (z_1 \ldots z_k)$: then 

$$\max_{j=1 \ldots n} \lvert(x, y_j)\rvert \lesim \lVert Px \rVert = \sqrt{\sum_{l=1}^k\lvert (z, y_l) \rvert^2} \lesim \max_{l=1\ldots k} \lvert (x, z_l)\rvert$$

where $\lesim$ stands for: "lesser or equal up to a multiplicative constant".

Comment: Anyway, as for what my professors say: I believe that they simply forget to say "sequentially" in ($T$ is compact iff $T$ is weak-norm *sequentially* continuous). IMHO this is not a mortal sin for somebody not working in strictly theoretical issues.

Answer (score 11):

There is the following characterization of compactness:

An operator $T: H \to H$ is compact if and only if $T|_{B} : B \to H$ is continuous, where $B$ is the closed unit ball of $H$ equipped with the weak topology and $H$ is equipped with its usual norm topology.

You can find a proof of this fact e.g. in Pedersen's *Analysis Now* as part of Theorem 3.3.3. However, this result relies heavily on net techniques, but you could take the opportunity to learn about that in Chapter 1 of that book.

To see that continuity implies compactness in your sense, simply observe that continuity implies that $T(B)$ is compact, and as $T(B)$ is metrizable, every sequence in $B$ has a subsequence whose image under $T$ converges. The other direction is a bit more complicated but not really difficult.

---

Now suppose that $T: H \to H$ is weak-norm continuous. Then the seminorm on $H$ given by $x \mapsto \|Tx\|$ is continuous as a map $(H, \text{weak}) \to \mathbb{R}$, so by a standard result on locally convex spaces and the definition of the weak topology (see also Tim's answer to your question), there are points $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n} \in H$ such that
$\|Tx\| \leq \max{\{|\langle x,x_{i}\rangle|\,:\,i = 1,\ldots,n\}}$ for all $x \in H$. But this means that $T$ must vanish on the orthogonal complement of the span of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, so certainly $T$ has finite rank.

Comment: Great! This is exactly the answer I expected. Now I need to chew it up a little. Thank you for the bibliographical reference also.

Comment: Great! Take your time... I'll think about how I could make the thing a bit easier to digest.

Comment: @dissonance: the standard result I was referring to is of course exactly what Tim is explaining in his answer. The condition $\|Tx\| \leq \max{\{\ldots\}}$ is equivalent to the statement that $T$ is continuous at zero from $(H,\text{weak}) \to (H,\text{norm})$ and this in turn is equivalent to the statement that $x \mapsto \|Tx\|$ is a continuous semi-norm on $(H,\text{weak})$. This is completely analogous to the statement you're used to for (semi-)normed or Banach spaces.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact) of mine.

Comment: Thanks to you and Tim we have solved Reed & Simon's problem for linear $T$. However, the text does talk of a generic *map*, not necessarily linear: in fact the problem is marked as *very difficult*! I'm certainly not willing to go into this, since it is far beyond my possibilities at the moment. Just wanted to point it out for the curious (and advanced) people.

Comment: @dissonance: Could you please give the reference to the problem in Reed & Simon? I'm not quite sure what the precise "very difficult" statement is you're mentioning.

Comment: @Theo: Of course. It is Problem VI.34 on page 219 of volume I (1980 edition). Here you have a screenshot of the text: 

http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/1872/problemareedsimon.png

Comment: @dissonance: Thanks! Are you sure that this is really meant to apply to non-linear maps? For instance in problem 10 on p.217 the (linear) Volterra operator is also referred to simply as a map. Besides, I don't know what the rank of a non-linear map is supposed to be (well, if $f$ is differentiable you could define it as $\operatorname{rk}{df}$, but that would be mentioned for sure). Moreover, the statement doesn't *feel right* even if I can't come up with an explicit counterexample at the moment.

Comment: @Theo: No, I'm not sure at all. The only thing that makes me think there's something more to the problem is that star before problem number, meaning "hard". But your objections are convincing.

Comment: @dissonance: Well, the solutions given here are not exactly *easy*, are they?

Comment: @Theo: No, no, not so *easy*!!!  :-) You know, when I see those "very difficult" exercises, I usually think "I will never be able to understand that"... Turns out that it's not always the case! Thank you and sorry that I made you waste your time.

Comment: @dissonance: I guess difficulty is always in the eye of the beholder. My impression is that these marks in RS are indicating that the solutions are not entirely routine from what's being said in the chapter they belong to and need some deeper grasp of the text. However, as little as I can tell from what you've shown on this site so far: I have no doubts whatsoever in your potential. All it needs is a bit more practice and experience. Trust me on that, keep up the good work and *enjoy doing what you do*. No worries about my time, it  didn't feel like it was wasted :)

Comment: @Theo: To receive comments like this from people like you is most encouraging!!! Thank you very much and have a nice Sunday.