# $L^2(U)$ compact embedded in $H^{-1}(U)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be an open subset of $R^d$. We already knew that $L^2(U)$ is a subset of $H^{-1}(U)$.  Question: is this a compact embedding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this embedding is compact. This can be seen, since this is the adjoint of the embedding of $H_0^1(U)$ in $L^2(U)$.

Comment: thank you. Can you please add some more detail or some references for the fact that the duality preserve the compact embedding property?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact.

Comment: thank you. your answer is very helpful