# If $T:X\to Y$ is continuous and $T^{t}:Y^{*}\to X^{*}$ is compact, is it true that $T$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question. I have Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, and $Y$ is reflexive. If $T:X\to Y$ is continuous, and $T^{t}:Y^{*}\to X^{*}, T^{t}(\phi)=\phi \circ T$ is compact, is it true that $T$ is compact?

Thanks so much

Comment: Yes, if $T\colon X \to Y$ with Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, then $T$ is compact if and only if $T^t$ is compact. No reflexivity or anything fancy needed.

Comment: an idea to show it

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to write it up.

Comment: Or what David posted. Would you then still need an answer here?

Comment: @DanielFischer I just  noticed [that post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact) only  proved the other implication.

Comment: @DavidMitra But that means we know $T^{tt} \colon X^{\ast\ast} \to Y^{\ast\ast}$ is compact, and that means that $T(B_X)$ is totally bounded (as a subset of a totally bounded set, $T^{tt}(B_{X^{\ast\ast}})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes. I was just pointing out my (deleted) link does not give the solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer  yes, any idea, only, thanks

Comment: @user89940 Sorry, I don't understand. Does that mean you want an answer here, or the other post together with the comment above is enough?

Comment: [Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1298) is an alternative proof (I haven't checked it). Although I suggest you first prove that if $T$ is compact,then so is $T^*$ (as in the previous link): then use Daniel's argument.

Comment: well, if $B$ is unit closed ball in $X$. i wanna show that $\overline{T(B)}$ is compact in $Y$, and what can i do to use hypothesis of $T^{t}$ is compact. thanks

Comment: This is known as Schauder's theorem and can be found in most functional analysis textbooks.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge thanks now i find it

Answer (score 4):

Just to save this answer from being unanswered

1) See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact) for implication $T \mbox{ compact }\implies T^* \mbox{ compact}$

2) For reverse implcation note that from 1) it follows that $T^{**}$ is compact. By $i_E$ we denote isometric embedding of $E$ into its the double dual, then it is easy to check that $i_Y T=T^{**} i_X$. Since $T^{**}$ is compact so does $ T^{**}i_X$ and $i_Y T$. Since $i_Y$ is isometric this implies that $T$ is compact.

Comment: Could you spell out the details as to why $i_Y$ being isometric implies that $T$ is compact, please?

Comment: @maths_student, $T$ is compact if $T(B_X)$ is totally bounded. The notion of total boundedness is invariant under maps that preserve distance.