# Compactness of Banach A and A' equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness

Case
\begin{equation*}
A \in \mathscr{B}(X,Y) \, \text{compact} \Leftrightarrow A' \in \mathscr{B}(Y',X') \, \text{compact}.
\end{equation*}
where $X,Y$ are Banach spaces.

### My proposal

Let $\eta_{n}$ be a sequence in $\mathscr{B}(X,Y)$ and 
$\mathbb{K} = \mathscr{B}'(Y',X')$. 
Consider the functions
\begin{equation*}
\psi_{n}(y) = \eta_{n}, \, y \in C(\mathbb{K}), \, \eta_{n} \in \mathscr{B}_{Y'}(X,Y).
\end{equation*}
The functions are equicontinuous and $\mathbb{K}$ is compact. 
So there is a converging subsequence $\psi_{n}$.

Comments

- I am not sure if the convergence has to be shown here.
- Taking sequences and applying them functions is intuitive but I would like to know better approaches and/or more rigorous if available.

Sources

- Compact operators, [here](http://people.sissa.it/~bianchin/Courses/Functionanal/lecture08.compactope.pdf#page=2)

---

How can you prove the compactness of the adjoint Banach space with the compact origin space too?

Comment: I believe the title is "To show compactness of adjoint operator on Banach space", isn'n it? Compactness of [$A$ and $A'$ are equivalent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact).

Comment: This is *Mazur's theorem*.

Comment: @Jochen Sorry, I verified this. This is not *Mazur's theorem*. Do you mean that it applies to some part here?

Comment: It is a theorem of Schauder, not Mazur.