# Self-adjoint and compact operator on $L_2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Define the linear operator $T : L_2[0, 1] \rightarrow L_2[0, 1]$ by
$$Tf(x) = \int_0^x \int_y^1 f(z)\,dz\,dy$$
I want to prove the operator is self-adjoint and compact.

Here's my attempt. For the self-adjoint part, we have for $f,g\in L_2[0, 1]$
$$\langle f,Tg \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) Tg(x)dx$$
$$ = \int_0^1 f(x)(\int_0^x\int_y^1g(z)dzdy)dx$$
$$ = \int_0^1 \int_0^x\int_y^1  f(x)  g(z)dzdydx $$
$$ = $$

Comment: The following link has some general results in this direction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator

Comment: this is like a double application of the Volterra operator defined by $V(f):=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ for $f\in L^2([0,1])$. If you can show that this operator is compact you are almost done (the self-adjointness of $T$ follows from it definition)

Comment: @Masacroso This is the answer to the question! Actually $T(f)=V(V^*(f))$ and by Schauder's theorem ( cf.[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact)) $V^*$ is compact if and only if $V$ is compact, though boundedness of one of them and compactness of the other would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will let you show that $T$ is self-adjoint.

Observe
\begin{align}
T(f)(x) =&\ \int^1_x\int^{x}_0 f(z)\ dydz+\int^x_0 \int_0^z f(z)\ dydz\\
=&\ \int^1_x xf(z)\ dz+\int^x_0 zf(z)\ dz\\
=&\ \int^1_0[x\cdot\chi_{[x, 1]}(z)+z\cdot \chi_{[0, x]}(z)]f(z)\ dz\\
=&\int^1_0 k(x, z) f(z)\ dz
\end{align}
where $k(x, z) = x\cdot\chi_{[x, 1]}(z)+z\cdot \chi_{[0, x]}(z)$. To show that $T$ is compact, it suffices to show that $T$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. In particular, it suffices to show that
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\int^1_0|k(x, z)|^2\ dxdy<\infty. 
\end{align}
But that's clear since $k(x,z)$ is a bounded function on $[0, 1]\times [0, 1]$.

Comment: Don't You mean $k(x,z)=x\cdot\chi_{[x,1]}(z)+z\cdot\chi_{[0,x]}(z)$? I don't understand the first equation, it looks like the variable $y$ in the bound of the integral is lost somewhere...?

Comment: @PeterMelech Yes. It was a typo. The first line is just Fubini. It should be clear once you draw the picture of the domain of integration.

Comment: Could you explain the first line "T(f)(x) =&\ \int^1_x\int^{x}_0 f(z)\ dydz+\int^x_0 \int_0^z f(z)\ dydz" and what does $\chi_{[x,1]}$ mean?