# Adjoint operator of compact operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following problem:
Given $H$ a Hilbert space, and $T\in\mathcal{L}(H,H)$ a compact operator. Show that $T^*$ is 
compact, where $T^*$ is the adjoint of $T$. (That is the operator defined by $
\langle Tx,y\rangle
=
\langle
x,T^*y
\rangle
$,$\forall x,y\in H$).

This is given in a class exercise where it is suggested that we use that $T^*T$ is compact. Currently I have absolutely no idea on how to use this.

There are other threads 
such as
[Easy Proof Adjoint(Compact)=Compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41432/easy-proof-adjointcompact-compact)
where a solution is given. However, they use heavy machinery currently out
of reach, such as Banach-Alaouglu's or Arzeli-Ascoli's theorem.
There must be a simple solution, anyone got a clue?

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Do you know that "an operator is compact iff it is the operator-limit of a sequence of finite-rank operators"?

Comment: Also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1281028/266110) doesn't seem to use any heavy machinery.

Comment: @SahibaArora Only if $H$ is separable, which is not necessarily the case

Comment: @SahibaArora It uses that every bounded sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence, which is basically the Banach-Alaoglu's theorem