# Is compact operator weak-to-norm continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis

1. Can we say a compact operator is weak-to-norm continuous?
2. What do we say about converse of question 1?

Comment: Is the underlying space a Banach space or a Hilbert space?

Comment: Please read: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Answer (score 5):

For part 2., more can be said: If $T:X\rightarrow Y$ is weak-to-norm continuous where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then $T$ has finite rank. One can prove this using an argument similar to those in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170416/different-types-of-continuity-for-operators-on-hilbert-spaces/170419#170419) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41317/is-compactness-a-stronger-form-of-continuity/41321#41321) (Use the fact that the inverse image under $T$ of the unit ball of $Y$ is weakly open to find $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ in $X^*$ so that $\Vert Tx\Vert\le 1$ whenever $|x_i^*x|<1$ for all $i$. Then show that the kernal of $T$ must contain the subspace $\cap_{i=1}^n \text{ker}( f_i)$ of $X$. This subspace has codimension at most $n$; thus $T$ has rank at most $n$).

In light of this fact,  your first question becomes: is every compact operator of finite rank?
The answer of course is "no", in general (however, recall that a compact operator between Banach spaces is weak-to-norm *sequentially* continuous).

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (2): the closed unit ball is weakly compact in any reflexive Banach space (as pointed out by t. b.)

Comment: Well, no one said we have a reflexive space here.

Comment: @t.b. That's right. I was reading some paper on $C^*$-algebras so I had a Hilbert space on my mind. I'll leave the answer in case the OP was about reflexive spaces.

Comment: Sure, sorry that was a rather silly nitpick. It's a good hint for various converses...