# Prove that $T(E)$ is finite dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, weak-topology

I have been working on the following problem.

> Let $E$ and $F$ are two Banach spaces and $T\in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ (the space of bounded linear operators from $E$ into $F$.)  Suppose that $T$ is continuous from weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$ of $E$ to norm topology of $F$. Letting $F'=T(E)$, prove that $B_{F'}$ is compact.

Here, $B_{F'}$ is the closed unit ball in F'.

I have been trying to prove $B_{F'}$ is compact since then $T(E)$ is automatically finite dimensional by the consequence of Riesz lemma.

I even don't know if this is true or not. I just guess it should be true but I don't know why. I am keeping trying to find a convergent subsequence of any given sequence $(u_n)\subset B_{F'}$ but have not gotten anyting. Could anybody help me?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: To check, $B_{F'}$ is the closed unit ball in the Banach space $T(E)$?

Comment: @Reveillark  Yes! That is closed unit ball! I forgot to mention it. sorry!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178581/is-compact-operator-weak-to-norm-continuous).

Comment: @DavidMitra  Thanks!